# Let $L$ be the language defined by the regular expression $(a \vee b \vee c)(a \vee b \vee c)$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

1) How does $|L|  = 9$?

2) $|L^*| = \aleph_0$?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS:

1. Either use the [multiplication principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), or write out all words of the language in systematic fashion from the regular expression.
2. If $w\in L$, then $w,ww,www,\ldots\in L^*$. With a little more work you could actually say exactly what the lengths of words in $L^*$ are, and how many of each length there are.

Answer (score 2):

**1)**
Notice there are two groups with three distinct possibilities each, so
$$|L| = 3^2 = 9$$
More specific
$$L = \{aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc\}\tag{1}$$

---

**2)**
You want to show that $L^\ast$ is countably infinite. $L^\ast$ is infinite since $|L| > 0$.
Now think of how to enumerate the elements of $L^\ast$ given an enumeration for $L$
$$L \stackrel{(1)}\simeq \{1,\ldots, 9\}$$

Comment: the reason why i ask is, (a U b U c) can be: 1)a 2)b 3)c 4)ab 5)ac 6) bc 7) abc 8)$\lambda$ if so, then how does it become 3 x 3 ? shouldn't it be a lot more like 8 x 8?

Comment: @user1486802 No, $(a \vee b \vee c)$ is 1) $a$ or 2) $b$ or 3) $c$. This is not a subset of $\{a,b,c\}$ (of which there are 8 possibilities indeed), but a single element of $\{a,b,c\}$ (with three possibilities).

Comment: @user1486802 By the way, use $\$\text{\vee}\$$ for the correct symbol ($\vee$)

Comment: @dtldarek, oh.. Now it all makes sense. such a newbie Q. Thanks alot!

Comment: @AlexR, thanks a lot for the answer!